# Query to find the 'Branch_Code' of the 'Channel_Num' with the lowest 'Issue_Date' using T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, query

Hope you're doing well

I have a table with the structure below :

```
Customer_Channel_Branch:(Customer_Num int ,Channel_Num int ,Branch_Code int ,Issue_date  datetime)
```

Some Example Data :

```
                  "Customer_Channel_Branch"
---------------------------------------------------------
Customer_Num     Channel_Num    Branch_Code    Issue_date  
    x                 1             1000         1990
    x                 2             2000         1991
    x                 3             3000         2000
```

There is another table with this structure below:

```
 Channel_general_Code:(Channel_Num  int , Channel_gnrl_Code  int)
```

some example data for this table:

```
            "Channel_general_Code"
-------------------------------------------
     Channel_Num     Channel_gnrl_Code
        1                 1
        2                 1
        3                 1
```

As you can see in the second table , all three `Channel_Num --> (1,2,3)` are grouped as one single channel . So what I want in the result set is this :

```
                    "result"
----------------------------------------------
Customer_Num     Channel_Num     Branch_Code
    x               1               1000           
    x               2               1000
    x               3               1000
```

for `Channel_Num`s that are considered as one , (have the same `Channel_gnrl_Code` in the second table), I need the `Branch_Code` of the `Channel_Num` with lowest `Issue_date`.
I thought that I could use `window functions`

```
(`row_number() over(partition by Channel_gnrl_Code order  by Issue_date )`)
```

to write this query but it gave me a false result.
I was wondering if you could help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: No one knows any solutions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `Row_Number` because first it process whole table then again you select row
where rn=1 for each group

```
DECLARE @Customer_Channel_Branch TABLE (
    Customer_Num VARCHAR(10)
    ,Channel_Num INT
    ,Branch_Code INT
    ,Issue_date INT
    )

INSERT INTO @Customer_Channel_Branch
VALUES (
    'x'
    ,1
    ,1000
    ,1990
    )
    ,(
    'x'
    ,2
    ,2000
    ,1991
    )
    ,(
    'x'
    ,3
    ,3000
    ,2000
    )

DECLARE @Channel_general_Code TABLE (
    Channel_Num INT
    ,Channel_gnrl_Code INT
    )

INSERT INTO @Channel_general_Code
VALUES (
    1
    ,1
    )
    ,(
    2
    ,1
    )
    ,(
    3
    ,1
    );

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT a.*
        ,b.Channel_gnrl_Code
    FROM @Customer_Channel_Branch A
    INNER JOIN @Channel_general_Code B ON a.Channel_Num = b.Channel_Num
    )
SELECT c.Customer_Num
    ,c.Channel_Num
    ,ca.Branch_Code
FROM CTE C
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 Branch_Code
    FROM CTE C1
    WHERE c.Customer_Num = c1.Customer_Num
        AND c.Channel_gnrl_Code = c1.Channel_gnrl_Code
    ORDER BY c.Issue_date
    ) ca
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Are you saying that using row_number might may give a false result or something ? or does it just have performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

I found a query to solve this :
first of all I should say that I change the structure of the first table and added`Channel_gnrl_Code` the first table `Customer_Channel_Branch` and then used the below query .

```
select t2.customer_number , 
       t2.Channel_Num,
       t1.Branch_Code,
       t1.Channel_gnrl_Code
from (
       select b.*
       from (select a.customer_number,
                    a.Channel_Num,
                    a.ch_name,
                    a.branch_code,
                    a.Channel_gnrl_Code,
                    a.issue_date,
                    row_number() over(partition by a.Channel_gnrl_Code order by  a.issue_date) r_num
             from Customer_Channel_Branch a) b
       where r_num = 1) t1 
inner join Customer_Channel_Branch t2 
 on t1.Channel_gnrl_Code = t2.Channel_gnrl_Code
```

Does anyone know any better solution? Is this query convenient in terms of performance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you think using the window function Row_Number might produce false result?